# Lubuntu 19.04 - No Startup Notification Cursor

Tags: mouse, desktop-environment, lubuntu, cursor

When I double click an application, ex: Firefox, the mouse cursor does not change to a spinning one until the application fully loads.

I have specified:

> StartupNotify=true
>
> X-KDE-StartupNotify=true

with no luck.

I have lxqt-notificationd, notification-daemon installed and running.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

I posted this same question in the LXQT Forum Support Section since I thought that it was also a good place to find support regarding the topic.

I was told that LXQt doesn’t have startup notification to date. An old feature request was made (https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/issues/703), which is repeated here: (https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/issues/1554)

You can read the whole discussion here: https://forum.lxqt.org/t/lubuntu-19-04-no-startup-notification-cursor/803